# structure not recognized inside a function other than main

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters, structure

I'm working on my assignment and I'm currently stuck in an error which I don't know how to solve. I've got a function add_name where I try to add a node to a doubly-linked-list, but the structure is not recognized inside the function, giving me the following error:

"request for member 'first' in something not a structure or union"

My program has the main file, a header file and another file "functions", where I write the functions, since we're currently learning how to program in a modular way. 
Here is a code snippet with my work, I hope I've been clear enough.

In the header file:

```
typedef struct node
{
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
char name[50];
}NodeT;

typedef struct list_header
{/*header cell for the list*/
NodeT *first;
NodeT *last;
}child_list;

void add_name(child_list **p, char[]);
```

In main after creating the list I just call the function add_name like this:        add_name(&prime_list,name);

In functions:

```
void add_name(child_list **p_list, char name[]{
NodeT *p;
p = (child_list*)malloc(sizeof(child_list));
strcpy(p->name,name);
if (p_list==NULL)
{/*list is empty*/
    p_list->first=p_list->last = p;
    p_list->first->next=p_list_first->prev = NULL;
    p_list->last->next=p_list->last->prev = NULL;
    p_list=p;
}
```

Shortly said, this is the problem I'm facing now, I did my research on this but still haven't found an answer, it doesn't seem that I'm doing anything wrong.

The above question was solved, but I've got another, when I try to create the list in a function, all the specifications remain the same. (it's about the same program)

```
void create_circular_list (child_list** p_list)
{/*creates an empty list; reserves memory for the header cell*/
p_list =(child_list*)malloc(sizeof(child_list));
(*p_list)->first=(*p_list)->last=NULL;
(*p_list)->first->next=(*p_list)->first->prev=NULL;
(*p_list)->last->next=(*p_list)->last->prev=NULL;}
```

The program crashes instantly and I've figured the problem is in this function. I call it this way in main:

```
    create_circular_list(&prime_list);
```

Comment: at what line you are getting error

Comment: after if(p_list==NULL) right when I try to assign p

Comment: `p = (child_list*)malloc(sizeof(child_list));` : `p` type different.

Comment: in `if` block, place `*` before all p_list. eg: `(*p_list)->first`

Comment: `p_list->first=p_list->last = p;` : p_list should not have referred to case of `NULL`.

Comment: I did put * before, but without the parentheses, now that problem is solved, thank you very much. If I'm facing another problem (at strcpy line), should I reedit my post or ask it here? :D And how should I mark my question as answered if the answer is in the comments section?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
NodeT *p;
```

to

```
struct child_list *p;
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the whole problem, which was resolved above, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In

```
void create_circular_list (child_list** p_list)
{/*creates an empty list; reserves memory for the header cell*/
    p_list =(child_list*)malloc(sizeof(child_list));
```

remove the last line. Variable `p_list` is assigned value when you call the function, you don't need to assign it a new object (anyway, even if you needed, you do that wrong).

**EDIT**

Sorry, I didn't guess, you have not shown the declaration. Generally it's not a good practice to declare a pointer variable and not assign it a value. You can do that if an assignment follows soon, but if is done somewhere else, in other functions, it's better to initialize a pointer either to point at some already existing object, or by immediate allocation or just by giving it a NULL value.

So, assuming the declaration

```
child_list *prime_list;
create_circular_list(&prime_list);
```

you have a pointer to a pointer to a `child_list` object in `create_circular_list` function, just as you declare:

```
child_list **p_list
```

Then you allocate a memory block for a `child_list` object and have a pointer to it. So you should not assign it to `p_list` but rather to `prime_list`, i.e. to a pointer pointed to by `p_list` – just add a star in front of the assignment's left side:

```
*p_list = (child_list*)malloc(sizeof(child_list));
```

Next you properly initialize the list object to show the list is empty:

```
(*p_list)->first = (*p_list)->last = NULL;
```

(although you might check before, if the pointer returned from `malloc` is not NULL) but then...

```
(*p_list)->first->next = (*p_list)->first->prev = NULL;
```

you try to assign `NULL` to member fields of a structure 'pointed to' by `(*p_list)->first`. And `(*p_list)->first` has been assigned `NULL` a moment before! You store data under invalid address, which causes a memory access exception and the program gets terminated.

Comment: In main the variable which is given as a parameter, namely prime_list is just a pointer, which was declared like: child_list *prime_list, without being given any adress. That's why I reserve memory for it in the function. At least it's what I've learned at university :D